# Php datas a faltar 10 dias

Tags: php, data

Estou com uma duvida e gostaria de saber se é possivel neste código em vez de mostrar datas ja expiradas mostrar datas que faltem 10 dias para expirar.

```
 if(!empty($row[10]) AND ($row[11] < time() || $row[12] < time() || 
 $row[13] < time() || $row[14] < time() || 
 $row[15] < time() || $row[16] < time() || 
 $row[17] < time())){
```

Em vez de aparecer o time que é a data actual que seja a data que faltam 10 dias.

PS: No exemplo que coloque mostra-me as datas que ja estão expiradas. Eu agora só quero mostrar as datas cujo a data falta 10 dias para expirar.

Comment: Esclareça seu problema específico ou acrescente outros detalhes para destacar exatamente o que precisa. Do modo como está escrito aqui, é difícil saber exatamente o que você está perguntando. Consulte a página [ask] para obter ajuda no esclarecimento desta pergunta.

Comment: não percebi muito bem a questão. mas quer ir buscar a data 10 dias antes da data actual? Por exemplo, hoje é dia 6-08-2014, quer receber 27-07-2014????

Comment: Exacto. Buscar 10 dias antes

Comment: Veja as funções [Date/Time](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ref_date.asp) do PHP

Answer (score 1):

Vamos imaginar que a data é 2014-07-29, para ir buscar 10 dias atrás desta data basta fazer o seguinte:

```
   <?php
       //Precisa de definir a função abaixo para evitar warnings
       date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
       //Sua data original
       $Date = "2014-07-29";
       //Modifica a data (10 dias atrás) 
       $data_actual = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($Date. ' - 10 days'));
       //Mostra resultado
       echo $data_actual;
    ?>
```